# @Async Spring gets recalled for every request of different sessions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have a spring @Async annotated method in a bean, then in the controller I call that bean's method on a user request, and I do it this way so I can get a progress back from that bean, and it works fine for that.

But when I open it from another session the controller appears to restart the method and the progress is back again to the start point.

How to do this correctly, I have a progress count number as a field in the bean. and I increment it in the @Async method then get back via AJAX request to in a controller that retrieves it from the bean.

but its like the controller have only one bean injected to it. or there is only one controller for the whole app, whats is wrong here ?

**EDIT**

I tested in with opening two different browsers and running the task but it gets reloaded in both.

Comment: Can you show the code in your `@Async` annotated method and the surrounding class, as well as the way the call to the `Async` method is executed?

Comment: @BhashitParikh Thanks alot for your comment, but I found the solution, it took me alot but I found it.

Comment: Well, you can post the solution here maybe, and accept it as answer.

Comment: well do it now, I totaly forgot, thanks @BhashitParikh :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently **Spring Controllers** are singletons per web app (and when you think about it they should be), so they are not thread safe if you have a component wired to it.

Meaning that suppose you have bean **A** wired to controller **AC** if two users send requests to an **AC** method that uses bean **A** at the same time, you'll have wrong values for both or you'll have bean reconstructing at each call, so if **user1** starts the task and after a while before the task is finished **user2** comes into play and wants to start it too, then **user1**' values will reset and so on.

To avoid this I found that you should make beans that are wired to controllers annotated with `Session Scoped` using annotations or xml.

in my case I used

```
@Scope("session")
```

You should never annotate the controller, as it won't work and if it does it will give weird behavior.

you should also (if using annotations like me) add `scoped-proxy="targetClass"` in your `<context:component-scan />` element